# Change my location indicator color in Google Maps SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, location, google-maps-sdk-ios

I use the default blue current location indicator of Google Map by following code.

```
mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
```

I need to change the color of it.  Is there any way I can change the color?

I understand if it wasn't possible I could use maker which appearance is configurable but if I keep updating maker position, it doesn't move as smoothly as the default location indicator.

Comment: Changing tintColor doesn't work for me...

Comment: I found the best answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18331086/customize-google-maps-blue-dot-for-current-location